# Multifile Python project issue

Tags: python

I am struggling with my latest Python project and require good ideas.

I have dozens of webcrawlers written with Python that all produce similar type of output, but the code itself differs a lot by crawler.
I run all these crawlers dynamically from one "main_runner" script that imports them all from a folder called "crawlers" like this:

main_runner.py:

```
import crawlers
```

The "main runner" script does a lot of database stuff and checking of data, sending emails etc.

I am constantly adding new webcrawlers and deleting some of them. That is why I would like my "main runner" script to import everything dynamically
so I wouldnt have to change any code in the main script ever and that is where my frustration starts.

In the "crawlers" folder I have modules: "crawler1.py, crawler2.py" etc then of course the `__init__.py` file. To get the `__init__.py` file to populate `__all__` I had to use this monstrosity:

`__init__.py` file:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob

modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
from . import *
```

And to actually run all my webcrawler modules in a loop inside my "main runner" script the only way I have discovered how to run them is this way:

main_runner.py file:

```
import crawlers

all_modules = crawlers.__all__

for module in all_modules:
    #run a function called "crawl_data" and pass url to it.
    data = getattr(getattr(crawlers,module),"crawl_data")("www.google.com")
```

This works, but I feel it is very messy.

So am I approaching this in a completely wrong way in the first place? Anyone have any better ideas? I would love for the ability to split my crawlers in to separate files and to run them dynamically. This would give me the ability to delete/add/edit the crawlers without editing the main script.